# Offset issue in Grouped bar chart in Vegalite

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

[image: expected chart][image]I want to create a Grouped Bar Chart , it look good when data is less but when data is large then bar overlap to each other [See chart in Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlAGwKYI1AJi9AQwE8IBXAFwJACMIKKIBbawqMACwgCcUQm4uXJhABfADQhGAB1bsuvZP0HCMYiSB5wcVVCAwAPaYpAAZLDlwB5btqhVRjybkIVC1AG6E0ZDAGcUAG1QAGFvS0JuAAIAWWgKDiiASQARKIBaKIBNHKyYmL4AJgAGAEYS0pBJGIxCPzJufz4w9gw0dIAVODAAawwKAOra+sa-KIA1b18UQsKAZglQ8LxI2PjE1Izs3PyisoqqkBq6hqalEOh4biZO7r6qIZPRiam1ZFKANgAOAHZFkDCmBW0Ti9g2aUyuTyBSUFQOjxGZxAAHVCHBiHAoAhTEk-BRbr1+odjoixpMfG9SgBOUrFf6AiIg9bJCHbHK7WH7YqFYnDU4Bc5sMBtAn3QZHPnPcnTd4AFjp4iWQJcTLBLK2UI5IDh3N5TyRF1gcGuoqJCP5LwpKFKsp+AFZ6csVWs1ZtITsYdquTzzaM+Kj0Zjsbj8V1CQ8Jfqya9rR9Sg7FQCnatQQl1e72Z6dXM9aTmkKRWGxbmLdK3iU-omGcCXWm3WzoXtysUc76DZdjTci2bI6TLTLSj9fo7lSnmfXNVmua3e-z-WiMVicXjTRGSaWY+8qVTZSPGbXwRqPU2SrKS37Ba12t2Buf-P3KVSPnua6nDxnG5zm2e2wKAR2TRvO9oytd4fipBMlX3N90wbLUdR-WcLxRBcg2XUM7h7dcpU3akaRfZ0YInY8vxKO1gPzK9V3FbD7zLGYfkrKDX3HVlJxPYpyN-ZoAK7TC10lOjcI+QoqQIsdXTYkivWbLikKRANF2DFcgN-B9rSpYpnyrZNVTrKTMw4j4KMvYVr34mjBJAmU5llMSdNHPT3zgqdm2M7jzl41dgPUrdZnEpzYPY0itJMlDAyXENvLU+jkFmH4Fgc6DWKPQyQp+MKWjM6ifNi2VPgCg8guknUMo8-8jUA-jcs3QpqSYpNHKK4i0pkiswsUtCotU+TrPLONdySljJNSz82uKL5MoLczw0sqNfI+Brq0IlKP3grlJvKw0rj48MatAn5OMKoiDLGnVNt6+cIuUjC9pizdGMKY7VpcjiqSmqibzmvtYoVZiVpGtbXJKd6tq8nraL6lA-sa5LAdekLQcupROsilTqvu0CYeWiT9NG9bylpD7sq+-aZWx3TmtOgm6uKTLwYx3rfIppqTvx4GifK1Gbuipnfue+Hgra0pKi26acsx8mBbxoGTxF+nKt2+4ybeFm4ZlhHhdF5HwqU9Dech5npecoW4XKYnCwslXoeN4rWrNn0de2zsDaso2hoBjXTf2c2udQtHbuVyXVdtlqzrKOYygtmbi2Dm2Pdxk2SojqOwcV135v5hPArDgnI+1yGrr17rGcNrP-sTu3w9KSPHcL0zLdm63kDV4aveTmvdTTnaM5+zdW89pP7ZTuurKLrr0buvn+9D6nXMjmd66TT6rbjlvZ-ZpsF4VnuIbd8vYbbofq+3v3rv1vfM5n7Oqc3r9I8Qpessb2Pp6xjfZfv4pH7Hzz08vvu78b5s0-jJB+HV-Y8wARuIBFcc5zy3pxaOEs35S2AS9b2nc5JPwZlPMu184G31ARUSO2Df66wnoHLC+8CGH0HlXPOoUxYrybmvAeldc7zyYU7XBQdUEh3QYLDukd3I625hfUuNDYF0I4Qgr+ZUnbi1Jmwj+msSHFAUTg-+kir7SJxvAu+YCNEQPPiXPBUi0GEJAWolOF0n5KNXvw+OViMHCImjvF20CcJ6MptYzBkc7HkPEWYvh+CfGs1ccPTuSN7EsNfmEyxMiDHEJTjE8hzsqrmN0Yk-RRCbHRJMcXSeoSLECJcUIqJcxOaKLif0b6MCcm+MiSfapWjd46MAY0iJFSWl0zPkUqhAlsllKSXk-x8tmEk0cQkkZuS-HCImTw7RWTOmzKaT0vOiyl7BOKdQ4ZzjRnzMqb7GpUzWFOPXoI9uxzR5Rh4sskp+zLnlOuS025eYUaQIkSshpIcAC6GhpCREIEwAUwQQBQBBW8f8aAeAAGVOAYCYGoSQXhQIgD8P0Hk-xIXIr4OYbAeBTCEBoG0AAQnUNomIUUgDRTKZQQgRA4qhfiiwRKSVtAuLC3gqLNwgAAMTFCFcKsQiZcXQoJZYYlpK0AADF4hwrgAALxpXSykiVQDitZYS3A0q2hoDgAICMaqDlaqUJK9lMqrAwBgJi41m5IIQpZeatluqOVoCsNIbocAKDEEOCa94zK8Uup1XC4gTA6Aeq9WAH1freWgVKEGiVrqw0RogGgRVKr-W1SFUm7VlhU2RuzeivwABHMgkQ1B5qUFkAAggYOAfgugUEwAADWLTKdI8pq1mFdTYOw9r0UyFFZq51IBW31sbXqtAtasQiHjZ22UjqzXjsnU2n187aV8sLj25tmBa0GoQFADt0LhT2AwLwHtE6G3rpbRgWdCBN0Bphiuvd975A8BPXwAQjKq1irHdextAAFCAeI4DQC-YG-9wbV03unZm1VuENVOpg4B9dvQEOQeXQBtd07TCGp9ZBl9OG4Puq5Z+hd0KaBoEIL0EdKHoVobfeRnlW70XUdoz0ejK6mMbowPK+wmHKOxl3Xx-DRqiOibvda21PYA3pFpFJzAAmKAscg7QGjdGlP8YVcqxDCbtKjpg2+ilmKDVQH0-Ss9FAL3cbHW+johhB30piLWjoUQQgcEiA4aD0K603pA2BiDwnnkMb4P5xtRYhNsZlE9Xz4XcPuvE4RkLxGYMRb8NOtTIWNOcbs+lxLMrosBprj2jLzH00UZi1RzTXGytrrfSp4rwl6s3rfepmZ+W-OFbaA+p9m4u3YZg3CsgNAKB8fU11vgI2aAVe5epjjWn4tKBm+Nu9KmFvpvwD21bfGmt6cgwVZbIAKXcGRIIBIkGSg9tOxcbgFnuAACVCC4DgGQJtEBpDmBgM5kZK7bs8Ae891772Oifce4gDgv3TVjoB-di9wO3t+DJfQRgTBvvQ9C-9yId2gcvaRyjhgzAIcICh5J47p3PW0djYd1rkW+N9cs+WQ6PaLW4C5WQJgx6QuDSM9Ct9KQDCSb+ZINbIg9DeEQMevQhhjB8DfQeqXoqQBCgUNQWXJgFcfsvZIGglLzNvFABr+XfHTNUos8ryA82ZdGE13t+IamNC4CFzbuXSgBdC40DAXTWbXd2-Wz7v9IADUSb9ybu9yWfOaBtXa9Xtvw+YBk7HjQ9QxsTbDyt0bYug+p+z2pjPIAZtzc-SnrP9v7Bx7d4XsvAeK+l7T7XigmGC+7cb5hjQNmDC6CN-H93fHHNd-UKiyA7BXBBCN+wCAr2sTUBd6AQgN7qA0ZlYzyvJg0PTtXxoZfnLKuKB71XjfZG9-K533KwPa++BH6Kwd7fSWCPd-0L32DU778ScBaBn14HpcH-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)
i want bar clearly display with eqaul width

Comment: Is this for Power BI?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want the result to be. Do you want the width of the chart to change according to the number of bars (step size)? Do you want the bars to be thinner with a fixed width chart?

Comment: sir, i always  want  bar show  clearly in chart  not overlap in any cases either data increase or bar increase

Comment: Are you OK with the width of the chart increasing?

Comment: i always used container as per vega-lite docs
if i increase width chart adjust how upto how ???

Comment: This isn't a Vega question but a logic question. Do you want the chart width to stay fixed and the individual bars to be reduced in width to fit OR do you want the bars to stay fixed width and the chart width to grow to accommodate them?

Comment: I want chart fit accordingly with width:"container" and all bar should be clearly visible

Comment: So you want the individual bars to be thinner and reduced in width?

Comment: Yes, The width of the chart is fixed, I require the bar width to decrease with increasing data, to prevent overlapping of bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
{"name": "BarWidth", "expr": "length(data('source_0'))/3/4"},
```

**UPDATE END**

You have a param named BarWidth - just reduce that number. Here I have made it 5.
[image]

```
{
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}, "top": {"anchor": "middle"}},
      "orient": {"expr": "LegendOrient"}
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201201",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 223
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201201",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1687
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201201",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1910
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201202",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 140
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201202",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1475
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201202",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1615
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201203",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 207
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201203",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1787
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201203",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1994
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201204",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 196
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201204",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1795
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201204",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1991
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201205",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 277
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201205",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1629
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201205",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1906
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201206",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 349
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201206",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 1922
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201206",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 2273
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201207",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 416
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201207",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 2197
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201207",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 2614
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201208",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 67
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201208",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 705
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201208",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 772
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201209",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201209",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201209",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201210",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201210",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201210",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201211",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201211",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201211",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201212",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201212",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201212",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201301",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201301",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201301",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201302",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201302",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201302",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201303",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201303",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201303",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201304",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201304",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201304",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201305",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201305",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201305",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201306",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201306",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201306",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201307",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201307",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201307",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201308",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201308",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201308",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201309",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201309",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201309",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201310",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201310",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201310",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201311",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201311",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201311",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201312",
        "Measures": "Cancel-Tickets",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201312",
        "Measures": "Confirm-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM": "201312",
        "Measures": "WaiyingLIst-Ticket",
        "Measures Value": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "ColorScheme", "value": "set2"},
    {"name": "LegendLabelBaseline", "value": "middle"},
    {"name": "LegendLabelColor", "value": "#000000"},
    {"name": "LegendLabelFontSize", "value": 13},
    {"name": "LegendLabellimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "LegendLabelOffset", "value": 5},
    {"name": "LegendLabelOpicity", "value": 1},
    {"name": "LegendSymbolOpicity", "value": 1},
    {"name": "LegendSymbolSize", "value": 200},
    {"name": "LegendSymbol", "value": "square"},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleX", "value": -40},
    {"name": "LegendOrient", "value": "top"},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelAngle", "value": -45},
    {"name": "XAxisTitle", "value": "Measures"},
    {"name": "TitleAlign", "value": "center"},
    {"name": "XAxisTitleAngle", "value": 0},
    {"name": "TitleAnchor", "value": "middle"},
    {"name": "XAxisPostion", "value": 1},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelSize", "value": 13},
    {"name": "XAxisTickSize", "value": 5},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "XAxisTitleColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "XAxisTitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "TitleLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "TitleOffset", "value": -10},
    {"name": "TitleFontColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "TitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "TitleBaseline", "value": "center"},
    {"name": "TitleText", "value": "MAT Chart"},
    {"name": "YAxisPostion", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisTickSize", "value": 2},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelSize", "value": 13},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "YAxisTitle", "value": "Measures Value"},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelAngle", "value": -45},
    {"name": "Subtitle", "value": ""},
    {"name": "SubTitleColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "SubtitleFont", "value": "bold"},
    {"name": "SubtitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "BarWidth", "value": 5},
    {"name": "BarCornerRadiusTopLeft", "value": 0},
    {"name": "BarCornerRadiusTopRight", "value": 0},
    {"name": "BarCornerRadiusBottomLeft", "value": 0},
    {"name": "BarCornerRadiusBottomRight", "value": 0},
    {"name": "BarOpacity", "value": 1},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleAngle", "value": 270},
    {"name": "LegendColumn", "value": 4},
    {"name": "TitleDx", "value": 0}
  ],
  "title": {
    "align": {"expr": "TitleAlign"},
    "anchor": {"expr": "TitleAnchor"},
    "baseline": {"expr": "TitleBaseline"},
    "color": {"expr": "TitleFontColor"},
    "dx": {"expr": "TitleDx"},
    "fontSize": {"expr": "TitleFontSize"},
    "limit": {"expr": "TitleLimit"},
    "offset": {"expr": "TitleOffset"},
    "subtitle": {"expr": "Subtitle"},
    "subtitleColor": {"expr": "SubTitleColor"},
    "subtitleFont": {"expr": "SubtitleFont"},
    "subtitleFontSize": {"expr": "SubtitleFontSize"},
    "text": {"expr": "TitleText"}
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "axis": {
            "labelAngle": {"expr": "XAxisLabelAngle"},
            "labelColor": {"expr": "XAxisLabelColor"},
            "labelFontSize": {"expr": "XAxisLabelSize"},
            "labelLimit": {"expr": "XAxisLabelLimit"},
            "position": {"expr": "XAxisPostion"},
            "tickSize": {"expr": "XAxisTickSize"},
            "title": {"expr": "XAxisTitle"},
            "titleAngle": {"expr": "XAxisTitleAngle"},
            "titleColor": {"expr": "XAxisTitleColor"},
            "titleFontSize": {"expr": "XAxisTitleFontSize"}
          },
          "field": "Calendar Month ID - YYYYMM",
          "sort": {"field": "id"}
        }
      },
      "height": 250,
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "Measures",
              "legend": {
                "columns": {"expr": "LegendColumn"},
                "labelBaseline": {"expr": "LegendLabelBaseline"},
                "labelColor": {"expr": "LegendLabelColor"},
                "labelFontSize": {"expr": "LegendLabelFontSize"},
                "labelLimit": {"expr": "LegendLabellimit"},
                "labelOffset": {"expr": "LegendLabelOffset"},
                "labelOpacity": {"expr": "LegendLabelOpicity"},
                "symbolOpacity": {"expr": "LegendSymbolOpicity"},
                "symbolSize": {"expr": "LegendSymbolSize"},
                "symbolType": {"expr": "LegendSymbol"}
              },
              "scale": {"scheme": {"expr": "ColorScheme"}},
              "title": ""
            },
            "xOffset": {"field": "Measures"},
            "y": {
              "axis": {
                "grid": true,
                "labelAngle": {"expr": "YAxisLabelAngle"},
                "labelColor": {"expr": "YAxisLabelColor"},
                "labelFontSize": {"expr": "YAxisLabelSize"},
                "labelLimit": {"expr": "YAxisLabelLimit"},
                "orient": "left",
                "position": {"expr": "YAxisPostion"},
                "tickSize": {"expr": "YAxisTickSize"},
                "title": {"expr": "YAxisTitle"},
                "titleAngle": {"expr": "YAxisTitleAngle"},
                "titleColor": {"expr": "YAxisTitleColor"},
                "titleFontSize": {"expr": "YAxisTitleFontSize"},
                "titleX": {"expr": "YAxisTitleX"}
              },
              "field": "Measures Value",
              "scale": {"zero": false},
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          },
          "mark": {
            "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {"expr": "BarCornerRadiusBottomLeft"},
            "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {"expr": "BarCornerRadiusBottomRight"},
            "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {"expr": "BarCornerRadiusTopLeft"},
            "cornerRadiusTopRight": {"expr": "BarCornerRadiusTopRight"},
            "opacity": {"expr": "BarOpacity"},
            "tooltip": true,
            "type": "bar",
            "width": {"expr": "BarWidth"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent", "shape": "independent"}},
      "width": "container"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the bar widh is still fixed. Could it dynamically decreased with increase in data from 20 value?